# V-autocomplete for input text

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How I can use v-autocomplete for `<input type="text">`

I need When the user clicks on the suggested text(under input), it is inserted into the input text

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, You want to fill the input text field with the selected option from the `v-autocomplete` dropdown. If Yes, Just curious to ask - *Why do you want to insert the selected option in the input as v-autocomplete by default showing the selected value ?*

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    selected: null,
    itemList: [{
       name: 'Item 1'
    },{
       name: 'Item 2'
    },{
       name: 'Item 3'
    },{
       name: 'Item 4'
    }]
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.6/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.6/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-autocomplete
      v-model="selected"
      :items="itemList"
      label="Select Item"
      item-text="name"
      item-value="name"
    >
    </v-autocomplete>
    <v-text-field v-bind:value="selected"></v-text-field>
  </v-app>
</div>
```